# Bijection between sets $A_{m,n}, B_{m,n}, C_{m,n}$

Tags: combinatorics

Here's a **part** of a past question from an entrance examination which leads me to some

> $$
>     A_{m,n}
>   = \{
>         (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dotsc, \alpha_m)
>       :
>         1 \leq \alpha_1 \leq \alpha_2 \leq \dotsb \leq \alpha_m \leq n
>     \}
> $$
>   given that $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $i$,
>   $$
>     B_{m,n}
>   = \{
>       (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dotsc, \alpha_m)
>       :
>       \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \dotsb + \alpha_m = n
>     \}
> $$
>   given that $\alpha_i \geq 0$ and $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $i$,
>   $$
>     C_{m,n}
>   = \{
>       (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dotsc, \alpha_m)
>       :
>       1 \leq \alpha_1 < \alpha_2 < \dotsb < \alpha_m \leq n
>     \}
> $$
>   given that $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $i$.
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0yhc.jpg).)

Are the sets $A,B,C$ bijective in any way? I am not sure of that but the question asked us to find the number of elements in $A_{m,n}$ and the solution says that since $A,B$ form a bijection, they have the same number of elements. Thus they just count the number in any one of $A,B$ and does for the other.

Please explain me how $A$ and $B$ forms a bijection. Also, if $C$ forms a bijection, do explain me that as well.

What I think is that they don't form a bijection directly. But when the number of elements are altered, we can make them form a bijection. Like, $A_{x,y}$ and $B_{r,s}$ might form a bijection where $x$ is not necessarily equal to $r$ and $y$ to $s$. In that case, we can create a bijection using the the idea of a path travelled from the origin to $(x,y)$ in the coordinate plane such that there's only rightward and upward movements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
1\le \alpha_1\le \alpha_2\le \dots \le \alpha_m\le n
$$
if and only if
$$
1\le \alpha_1<\alpha_2+1< \alpha_3+2<\dots < \alpha_m+m-1\le n+m-1
$$
if and only if
$$
(\alpha_1-1) + (\alpha_2-\alpha_1)+\dots+(\alpha_m-\alpha_{m-1})+(n-\alpha_m)=n-1
$$
and all the summands are nonnegative.

Comment: I think I can say that $A_{m,n}$ and $B_{m,n-1}$ form a bijection and similarly, they form a bijection with $C_{m,n+m-1}$. Right? Also, I think you wanted to write $n-1$ instead of $n$ in the last equation.

Comment: If I am counting correctly, I think you should have $A_{m,n}$ is in bijection with $B_{m+1,n-1}$; in that last equation, there are $m+1$ summands. But yes, both are in bijection with $C_{m,n+m-1}$. And the mistake has been fixed.

Comment: Oops, sorry, yeah, that's what I meant (typed it wrong). So basically see, in my post where I claim that the bijection is formed only when $A,B,C$ all don't have $\{m,n\}$ in their subscripts. I understand with more clarity now. Thank you!